# Responsive menu (iphone 5)

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass

My client has an iphone 5 and has issues scrolling in the responsive menu for the website http://www.arbores.be  (using safari)

I'm having trouble recreating the issue, does someone recognize the problem? How do I solve the scrolling issue?

My client has shown me a video of the issue
[screencapture phone](https://youtu.be/jKHsslPvRpo)

Here's the code for the responsive menu

```
.main-navigation {
            position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    transform: none;
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-height: 0;
            z-index: 9999;
    padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    .menu-toggle {
        float: right;
    }
    .menu-main_menu-container {
        background: $main__color;
    }
    ul {
        width: 100%;
      height: 93vh;
      background: $main__color;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: auto;
                bottom: auto;
                -webkit-transform: none;
        -moz-transform: none;
        transform: none;
                z-index: 9998;
      overflow-y: scroll;
       -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
        li {
            width: 100%;
          border-bottom: 1px solid darken($main__color, 10%);
          margin: 0;
          &:last-child {
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            border-bottom: 0;
          }
            a {
                @include font-size(16px);
              width: 100%;
                                color: #fff;
              padding: 5px 0 5px 24px;
                &:after {
                  display: none;
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Since we don't know what your code looks like we can only guess at the problem. But really, that would just be throwing darts a wall with no target.

Comment: what's the actually issue? scrolling in what way?

Comment: I've added the code for the menu and a screencapture my client set me.

Answer (score 0):

First you set the meta tag:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, 
maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

then check all the paddings you have given.
Also check the width you have set any width:100%

nothing works then try it with overflow:hidden

body, html { overflow-x:hidden; }